# Not able to access Tomcat from another machine in LAN

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

I have two web applications running under Apache HTTP server and these applications use ports 8080 and 100. Recently I have installed Apache Tomcat 7.0.42 and I have changed the port number in `server.xml` from 8080 to 9999 as another application under Apache HTTP Server is already using 8080.

I am able to access Tomcat from the local machine using `localhost:9999` and with `IP Address:9999`. But I am not able to access the Tomcat sever using `IP Address:9999` from another machine in the network.

I am able to access the other application running on ports 8080 and 100 from another machine.

To check if there is any port issue, I stopped the application which is using 8080 and given the same port to Tomcat but still Tomcat is not accessible from another machine. So it is evident that it is not a port issue.

I think Tomcat is not accepting remote requests and I assume I need to do some changes in the `server.xml` file to enable the remote access. Please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: Could you please add to your question the relevant portions of your apache config and `server.xml` files?